# Remove marker Google map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with a google map that i fill marker with ajax ( with .each ) 
I don't use any array

```
function parks() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/index.php/route/getParks', 
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data.results, function(k,e){
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(e.lat,e.lng);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng,
                        map: mapg,
                        title: 'Places',
                    });
                })
            }
        });
    }
```

Is there a solution or I am forced to do it with an array ?

Thanks

Comment: You will need an array of markers, iterate through your array and call `setMap(null);` on each marker, unless reloading the map is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want it to do without arrays. You need to search for whole `mapg` object, find the corresponding area about markers, find your marker and bla bla bla; very painful. Especially with the one-letter variable names.

Instead, define a global marker array: `markers = new Array();`

Fill your array when you are adding markers:

```
$.each(data.results, function(k,e){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(e.lat,e.lng),
        map: mapg,
        title: 'Places',
        id: k // you may want to give another value for easy recognition
    });

    // you may add like markers["myPlace"] = marker; for easy recognition
    markers.push(marker); 
});
```

Then you can get a marker by looking at `markers` array and remove from map:

```
markers["myPlace"].setMap(null);
// or you can search by id by looking markers[index].id in a loop
```